# Optional group except when it precede with a match

Tags: python, regex

I want to match any string that starts with . and word and then optionally any character after a space.

```
r"^\.(\w+)(?:\s+(.+)\b)?"
```

eg:

should match

```
.just one two
.just
.blah one@nine
.blah
.jargon blah
```

should not match

`.jargon`

I want this second group mandatory if first group is `jargon`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Python you can exclude matching only jargon using a negative lookahead, and then match 1 or more word characters

Then optionally match 1 or more whitespace characters excluding newlines followed by at least 1 or more characters without newlines.

```
^\.(?!jargon$)\w+(?:[^\S\n]+.+)?$
```

The pattern matches:

- `^` Start of string
- `\.` Match a dot
- `(?!jargon$)` Exlude matching jargon as the only word on the line
- `\w+` Match 1+ word characters
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `[^\S\n]+.+` match 1+ whitespace chars excluding newline and then 1+ chars except newlines
- `)?` Close non capture group and make it optional
- `$` End of string

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yUfUsK/1) and a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/pT1qSE).

Example

```
import re

strings = [
    ".just one two",
    ".just",
    ".blah one@nine",
    ".blah",
    ".jargon blah",
    ".jargon"
]

for s in strings:
    m = re.match(r"\.(?!jargon$)\w+(?:[^\S\n]+.+)?$", s)
    if m:
        print(m.group())
```

Output

```
.just one two
.just
.blah one@nine
.blah
.jargon blah
```

Answer (score 2):

One approach would be to phrase your requirement using an alternation:

```regex
^\.(?:(?!jargon\b)\w+(?: \S+)*|jargon(?: \S+)+)$
```

This pattern says to match:

```
^                    from the start of the input
\.                   match dot
(?:
    (?!jargon\b)\w+  match a first term which is NOT "jargon"
    (?: \S+)*        then match optional following terms zero or more times
    |                OR
    jargon           match "jargon" as the first term
    (?: \S+)+        then match mandatory one or more terms
)
$                    end of the input
```

Here is a sample Python script:

```py
inp = [".just one two", ".just", ".blah one@nine", ".blah", ".jargon blah", "jargon"]
matches = [x for x in inp if re.search(r'^\.(?:(?!jargon\b)\w+(?: \S+)*|jargon(?: \S+)+)$', x)]
print(matches)  # ['.just one two', '.just', '.blah one@nine', '.blah', '.jargon blah']
```

Answer (score 1):

You could attempt to match the following regular expression:

```
^\.(?!jargon$)\w+(?= .|$).*
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/GjFFN3/1)

If successful, this will match the entire string. If one simply wants to know if the string conforms to the requirements `.*` can be dropped.

`(?!jargon$)` is a *negative lookahead* that asserts that the period is not immediately followed by `'jargon'` at the end of the string.

`(?= .|$)` is a *positive lookahead* that asserts that the string of word characters is followed by a space followed by any character or they terminate the string.

Comment: I like the jargonzola